# How to SELECT Consecutive dates?

Tags: mysql

I have query that goes like that :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        S.date1 AS date1, 
        S.date2 AS date2,
        S.period AS period

FROM portfolio.scenario S 

WHERE S.date1 >= '2010-06-01' AND
      S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
      S.period = 'WEEK'
```

The output is :

```
"2010-06-01 00:00:00","2010-06-08 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-02 00:00:00","2010-06-09 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-03 00:00:00","2010-06-10 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-04 00:00:00","2010-06-11 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-07 00:00:00","2010-06-14 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-08 00:00:00","2010-06-15 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-09 00:00:00","2010-06-16 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-10 00:00:00","2010-06-17 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-11 00:00:00","2010-06-18 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-14 00:00:00","2010-06-21 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-15 00:00:00","2010-06-22 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-16 00:00:00","2010-06-23 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-17 00:00:00","2010-06-24 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-18 00:00:00","2010-06-25 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-21 00:00:00","2010-06-28 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-22 00:00:00","2010-06-29 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-23 00:00:00","2010-06-30 00:00:00",WEEK
"2010-06-24 00:00:00","2010-07-01 00:00:00",WEEK
```

What i need are only the consecutive dates startest with earliest date1 ;

```
    "2010-06-01 00:00:00","2010-06-08 00:00:00",WEEK
    "2010-06-08 00:00:00","2010-06-15 00:00:00",WEEK
    "2010-06-15 00:00:00","2010-06-22 00:00:00",WEEK
    "2010-06-22 00:00:00","2010-06-29 00:00:00",WEEK
```

Appreciate any help on the topic :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not optimum for performance to use functional clauses, but this will do the trick as long as the `S.period` remains at a week.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        S.date1 AS date1, 
        S.date2 AS date2,
        S.period AS period

FROM portfolio.scenario S 

WHERE S.date1 >= '2010-06-01' AND
      S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
      S.period = 'WEEK' AND
      DAYOFWEEK(S.date1) = DAYOFWEEK('2010-06-01');
```

Comment: You have any idea andy , how a general solution would be (not depending on S.period value) ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Sorry, I didn't look at your desired result close enough. This JOIN will sort out those dates that don't have an ending and beginning on the same day.

You need to cross join the table like so:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        S.date1 AS date1, 
        S.date2 AS date2,
        S.period AS period

  FROM portfolio.scenario S,
       portfolio.scenario T

 WHERE S.date1 >= '2010-06-01' AND
       S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
       S.period = 'WEEK' AND
     ( T.date2 = S.date1 OR
       S.date1 = '2010-06-01' )
```

The last condition needs the OR to include the first row as it can't be joined by `T.date2 = S.date1`.

Here you go.

Comment: it doesn't work , just keep running and then "Lost connection with server"

Comment: Can't really tell from what you provided about your setup. Are you executing this from a scripting language or directly on the DB?